# How to resolve path in a WIX custom action

Tags: wix

This custom action fails .

```
<CustomAction Id="SetIntegrityLevel" Return="check" 
  Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred"
  ExeCommand="cmd /c icacls UiProxy.exe /SetIntegrityLevel High &amp; pause" />
```

The business with `cmd /c blah blah &amp; pause` is my little trick for getting some visibility on what happened in a failed command line operation.

```
UiProxy.exe: The system cannot find the file specified.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is a bit of a surprise. UiProxy.exe definitely is in the folder specified by TARGETDIR.

Is there some way to resolve the INSTALLDIR symbol into the command string? I need to produce something like this.

```
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\UiProxy\UiProxy.exe" /SetIntegrityLevel High
```

Obviously I'll need to put the quotes in explicitly, something like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetIntegrityLevel" Return="check" 
  Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred"
  ExeCommand="icacls &quot;[INSTALLDIR]UiProxy.exe&quot; /SetIntegrityLevel High" />
```

Where I've put [INSTALLDIR] I need the symbol resolved. The question is how to express this.

Answer (score 0):

Later in code I didn't post because it's standard boilerplate, I noticed this:

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="UiProxy" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

Specifying the command line as

```
<CustomAction Id="SetIntegrityLevel" Return="check" 
  Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred"
  ExeCommand="cmd /c icacls &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]UiProxy.exe&quot; /SetIntegrityLevel High &amp; pause" />
```

produces a success message, so it appears the square brackets syntax was correct but TARGETDIR is the wrong symbol, it should be INSTALLFOLDER.

Comment: Generally if you want to use the location of an installed file (I assime UIProxy.exe is installed by your installer) you can just use [#UIProxy.exe's File ID] to specify the full path to the component. This is commonly used in Shortcuts.

Comment: I tried this and you are right. It's more maintainable so propose it as an answer explaining why it is a better way and I will accept it.

Comment: @PeterWone Can you suggest (when) the sequence to execute this CustomAction. I put it after InstallFiles (4000) still it says the program required is not installed.

Comment: Not really. I haven't touched WiX since this post.